# MS-Access 2007 on WinXP, can't break out of requery looping in Form_Current sub

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I set a form "frmMain" to automatically display when the database is opened by naming it in:  Access Options, Current Database, Display Form: frmMain.

In a lapse of judgement of enormous proportion, I included the statement `me.requery` at the beginning of the class object module Form_frmMain's `Private Sub Form_Current()` routine.

Now, whenever the database opens, it starts requerying over and over until after a second or so it displays a message:  "Run-time error '3420': Object invalid or no longer set."  Selecting End or Debug both have the same effect:  `me.requery` is highlighted in yellow and a new "Object invalid or no longer set." message is displayed.

I've tried multiple Ctrl-Breaks, and Escapes, and can't get the console to return any control to me.  I can kill the process with the Task Manager, but that of course doesn't let me get into the VBA code to remove my ridiculous `me.requery`.

Can someone help me out here?  Thank you!  Dave

Comment: [Bypass startup options when you open a database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Bypass-startup-options-when-you-open-a-database-f19b5792-5a85-4516-89b2-43a10f60f1c1)

Comment: @HansUp Thank you for your comment!  This did indeed do the trick!  Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you kill your program from task manager, open your db file(I assume it is .accdb) by pressing down the `shift+enter` keys.

After you open your file you`ll see your database screen in front of you. Just double click a module to open the VBA editor or simply press ALT+F11. Then, youll be able to find your function.

Comment: Opened, found, and fixed!  Thank you very much for your extremely prompt, concise and correct answer!  Dave